# ajax/jquery/javascript

Tags: ajax

I have a function that toggles a button:
now I would like to display the text next to the button in 2 different colors based on the response.

This is my code:

```
function toggleMustHave(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '{$ajaxUrl}&act=toggleMustHave',
        data: 'storeId={$storeId}',
        success: function(data){
            $('#mustHave').html('<span id="mustHave" >'+data['mustHaveButtonText']+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;-->&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'</span>');
            $('#mustHaveButton').text(data['mustHaveButtonText']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: After executing success you'll have two elements with id of 'mustHave'; the span you create, and its parent. This may cause errors later on.

Answer (score 1):

Change CSS class of your `#mustHaveText` in your `success` handler.

```
success: function(data){
    $('#mustHave').html('<span id="mustHaveText" >'+data['mustHaveButtonText']+      '&nbsp;&nbsp;-->&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'</span>');
    $('#mustHaveButton').text(data['mustHaveButtonText']);

    var text = $('#mustHaveText');

    text.removeClass('color1');
    text.removeClass('color2');

    if ( conditionOnReturnedDataHere()) {
        text.addClass('color1');
    } else {
        text.addClass('color2');
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to add 2 colors based on my condition I dont want to remove anything so should I just leave out this part (  $('mustHaveText').removeClass('color1');
    $('mustHaveText').removeClass('color2');
)

Comment: If your AJAX call happens only once, then yes, that code is unnecessary. If it happens more then once on the page, then you need to remove previously added color before adding current one.

Comment: I need to change text next to a toggle button to a different color based on the toggle value how would I do that

Comment: leave the `removeClass` lines as they are, then, as toggle state can be changed multiple times.

Comment: what is the syntax for  conditionOnReturnedDataHere() in jquery as when I place my condition in the page breaks,Thank you,Ive moved on to other tasks already but this one is bugging me,really appreciate your help,Im evaluating the value 1 or 0, 1 represents orange and 0 represent green.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two step:

1) The first is to add to you css two new classes, one for every different response you will receive

2) The second is to modify you "success" function to append the next you need after the button:

```
function toggleMustHave(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '{$ajaxUrl}&act=toggleMustHave',
        data: 'storeId={$storeId}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#mustHave').html('<span id="mustHave" >'+data['mustHaveButtonText']+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;-->&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'</span>');
            $('#mustHaveButton').text(data['mustHaveButtonText']);

            var yourClass // write here your condition

            $('<p class="'+ yourCLass +'">Your text response</p>').insertAfter('#mustHaveButton');
        }
    });
}
```

Remember to modify you "yourClass" value, depending on your result (you can use simply an if clause)

Comment: would you edit the code for me, please mind me asking as Im just a beginner and I need to have this done today function toggleMustHave(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '{$ajaxUrl}&act=toggleMustHave',
        data: 'storeId={$storeId}',
        success: function(data){
            $('#mustHave').html('<span id="mustHave" >'+data['mustHaveButtonText']+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;-->&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'</span>');
            $('#mustHaveButton').text(data['mustHaveButtonText']);
        }
    });
}

Comment: how would I declare yourClass, what is the syntax?, please specify